# Make responsive advertisement page html bootstrap

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am working on marketing  project and I want to allow clients to configure their landing page which will contain images as ads , the page layout will be some things like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                Horizontal ADS AS IMAGE                                   |                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  V  |                                                              | V   |
|  E  |                                                              | E   |
|  R  |                                                              | R   |
|  T  |                       MAIN                                   | T   |
|  I  |                                                              | I   |
|  C  |                                                              | C   |
|  A  |                                                              | A   |
|  L  |                                                              | L   |
```

I tried a lot of but without success . when the page opened by phone the design will be very bad , the left vertical image will display under the top horizontal image and then the main section and then the right vertical image will display under main section , 
I don't know how to let design stay as the it in computer in the main section I will add video , 
so please tell me how can I do it 
I tried with this code but as I said the design will be very bad when the page opened by phones

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 3 Responsive Layout Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-12">
            <img src="728x90.png"/>


    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
           <img src="fdf_9x_en.jpg" />
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-8">
            <h2>CSS</h2>
            <p>CSS is used for describing the presentation of web pages. The CSS tutorial section will help you learn the essentials of CSS, so that you can fine control the style and layout of your HTML document.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="fdf_9x_en.jpg" />
   </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Copyright 2013 Tutorial Republic</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> fdf_9x_en.jpg is vertical image

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS file? You need to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), and you can also use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) which will allow you to specify how things shrink and grow, and how much space they take up based on a percentage of the viewport. Hopefully these links will help you get a general idea of what direction you need to go in, because just viewing the HTML isn't too helpful.

Comment: thank you for your replay but these example for div and text that when it opened by phone the elements will be under each others and that possible because the elements were horizontal but what can I do for vertical image , that will make vertical images under each others and that impossible